Declare ct helper object outside table declaration scope in nftables
Here is a working example of how ct helper object is currently declared as per nftables docs
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

add table filter_4 {
    # TODO: Can helper object be declared outside the scope of table declaration scope?
    # ct helper stateful object
    # "ftp-standard" is the name of this ct helper stateful object
    # "ftp" is the in-kernel name of the ct helper for ftp
    ct helper ftp-standard {
        type "ftp" protocol tcp;
    }
}

The ct helper object is then used for ex. as follows:
add chain filter_4 new_out_4 {
    comment "New output IPv4 traffic"
}

# FTP (active and passive)
# Rule for initial ftp connection (control channel), setting ct helper stateful object to use
# "ftp-standard" is the name of the ct helper stateful object
add rule filter_4 new_out_4 tcp sport >1023 tcp dport 21 ct helper set "ftp-standard" accept

What I want to achieve is to know the syntax to declare ct helper object outside the table in similar fashion how sets are declared.
An example on how a set is declared outside table declaration scope
add set filter_4 multicast_proto { type inet_proto; comment "IPv4 multicast protocols"; }
add element ip filter_4 multicast_proto { udp, igmp }

In similar fashion I want to declare ct helper object for instance:
# Table declaration
add table filter_4

# Declare ct helper separately
add ct helper ftp-standard {
    type "ftp" protocol tcp;
}

This of course doesn't work, what's the syntax to add\declare ct helper like this?
It seems ct helper must be bound to a table (is this true?) therefore perhaps table name should be specified in above example.

The syntax is described in nft(8):

CT HELPER
add ct helper [family] table name { type type protocol protocol ; [l3proto family ;] }
delete ct helper [family] table name
list ct helpers

So for your case:

From shell (including proper shell escaping using ' where appropriate, nft itself doesn't care: it parses parameters the same however they are provided split):
nft add ct helper filter_4 ftp-standard '{ type "ftp" protocol tcp; }'


Or if already within nft context, simply:
add ct helper filter_4 ftp-standard { type "ftp" protocol tcp; }



